# QGIS: drag zoom via keyboard shortcut/ mouse wheel?

Tags: qgis, zoom

To zoom to a rectangle in ArcGIS, I always clicked and held the mouse wheel while pushing the control key. This was a very efficiant way for me to navigate through a map. Is there anything similar in QGIS that avoids to select the tool?

---

**EDIT**:

Maybe I have to be more precise in my question, since I still have the same problem:

My initial situation is: I'm in the "select feature" mode and want to stay in this mode. Now I want to zoom in a rectangle BUT without having to click on the "zoom in" button but only with the use of a hotkey/mousewheel. In ArcGIS I always used the mousewheel-click, which allowed me to be very quick in selecting features or editing features AND navigating through the map (avoids to go to the tool bar again and again).

So: with the left mouse button, I select features (active tool in the toolbar) and with the mousewheel, clicking and holding I "panned" (not active in toolbar!) and with Ctrl + mouse-wheel-click and holding I "zoomed in rectangle".

Is there any possibility to define the hotkey in QGIS?

Comment: Apologies but not sure I completely understand. Are you asking if it's possible to zoom in to each feature by a shortcut key?

Comment: no, i mean to zoom in by dragging a rectangle. sorry, i was not precise.

Comment: and this without selecting the zoom-tool

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest you can get is to assign a shortcut key to the **Zoom to selection** function. The default is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>  but you can change this to another key. Using this function will not affect the **Select Feature** tool:

[image: Zoom to Selection]

Answer (score 0):

It is the zoom tool.

select the zoom tool. left click and hold, drag rectangle.

This is from QGIS 2.6.1

[image]

Comment: Well, the asker of this question did explicitly want to _not_ switch the tool, so this "answer" is not an answer to the question.

Comment: Golar is correct. The asker requested that the tool not be switched. This does not answer the question.